# I want to save QrCode as image

Tags: c#, .net, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

this the code

```
[HttpGet("GenerateQrCode")]
public ActionResult<string> GenerateQrCode(string sellername, string vatregistration, string timestamp, string invoiceamount,
    string vatamoun)
{
    string ltr = ((char)0x200E).ToString();
    var seller = ConvertTLV("1", sellername);
    var vatno = ConvertTLV("2", vatregistration);
    var time = ConvertTLV("3", timestamp);
    var invamt = ConvertTLV("4", invoiceamount);
    var vatamt = ConvertTLV("5", vatamoun);
    var result = seller.Concat(vatno).Concat(time).Concat(invamt).Concat(vatamt).ToArray();
   
    return Ok(new
    {
        QrCode = Convert.ToBase64String(result)
    }) ;
}
```

i try to make this

```
[HttpGet("GenerateQrCode")]
public ActionResult<string> GenerateQrCode(string sellername, string vatregistration, string timestamp, string invoiceamount,
    string vatamoun)
{
    string ltr = ((char)0x200E).ToString();
    var seller = ConvertTLV("1", sellername);
    var vatno = ConvertTLV("2", vatregistration);
    var time = ConvertTLV("3", timestamp);
    var invamt = ConvertTLV("4", invoiceamount);
    var vatamt = ConvertTLV("5", vatamoun);
    var result = seller.Concat(vatno).Concat(time).Concat(invamt).Concat(vatamt).ToArray();

    string QrCode = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    byte[] qrCodeBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(QrCode);
    string filePath = "E:/qrcode.png";
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(qrCodeBytes))
    {
        stream.Position = 0; // Set the position to the beginning of the stream

        try
        {
            Image qrCodeImage = Image.FromStream(stream);

           
            qrCodeImage.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            // Handle the "Parameter is not valid" error
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return Ok(new
    {
        qrcode   = filePath
    }) ;
}
```

Comment: Do you try generate a qr code and save it as imagine? Do u have a specific question?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the byte array `qrCodeBytes` contains the raw binary data of the QR code, not an actual QR image. So trying to create an `Image` directly from it will not give you the result that you want. First you have to generate the QR Code itself.

To convert the binary data to an image, you need to use a QR code library to generate the image from the data. For example:

```
using QRCoder; 

QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(QrCode, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);

using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
{
  bitMap.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Png); 
}
```

The file path needs to be a fully qualified path, not just a file name.